# How to be on same line after using %c in my code?

Tags: c, for-loop, newline, c-strings, fgets

**PROBLEM:** I have to print a `string` *(character per character)* several times in a same line but as soon as upper loop executed once line changes. So how to print it in a same line?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char name[100];
    int m;
    printf("Enter the string\n");
    fgets(name, 100, stdin);                                        
    printf("Number of times you have to repeat the string\n");
    scanf("%d", &m);                                                
    int n = strlen(name);
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            printf("%c ", name[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

> INPUT:

> ```
>  Enter the string
> ```

> ```
>   I LOVE TO EAT
> ```

> ```
> Number of times you have to repeat the string.
> ```

> ```
>  3
> ```

> MY OUTPUT:

```
I L O V E T O E A T 
 I L O V E T O E A T 
 I L O V E T O E A T
```

> EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
I L O V E T O E A T I L O V E T O E A T I L O V E T O E A T
```

Comment: `\n` is getting appended to the end of the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add one more statement after the call of `fgets`.

```
fgets(name, 100, stdin);
name[ strcspn( name, "\n" ) ] = '\0';
```

That is `fgets` can append the input string with the new line character `'\n'` that you should remove.

Pay attention to that calling the function `strlen`  the value of which is used in the inner loop is inefficient.

You could write instead.

```
for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
{
    for ( const char *p = name; *p != '\0'; ++p )
        printf("%c ", *p);
}
```

Comment: This code should work